# Getting properties object in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a properties file called `xyz.properties`. Right now, I am able to load individual property of this file in my class annotated with `@Component` which is working perfectly fine.

However, I am thinking of making my project more modular, for which I need to read the whole `xyz.properties` file as one `properties` object so that i can pass it along. How can I do so ?

**Update**

Right now, I am loading individual property from the file like this

my **applicationContext.xml** has following entry

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:xyz.properties" order="2" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

and then i have the respective class as

```
@Component
public class XyzConfiguration {
    @Value("${client.id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${client.secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    ...
}
```

**What I mean by pass it along**

Right now, for each individual property I have to create a respective field in a class and then annotate it with respective property name. By doing so, I am making my nested module very `spring` framework specific. I might someday put this module on github for others as well and they may or may not use `spring` framework. For them it would be easier to create an object of this module by passing required parameters (ideally in case of a `Properties` object) so that my module will fetch the properties by itself.

Comment: How are you loading your properties file right now? Also, what do you mean by pass it along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code.

```
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import java.util.Properties;

private String fileLocator;
private Properties prop;
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

 public void init() throws IOException {
        //"fileLocator" must be set as a path of file.
        final Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(fileLocator);

        prop = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
    }
```

prop will have all values from your property file and then you can get any value by calling prop.getProperty() method.